# How to prevent the page refresh on link click in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the code below

```
protected void BubbleButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Expand")
    {
        string strMonth = string.Empty;
        string status = string.Empty;
        string strCategory = "";
        int idxCategory = 0;
        if (e.CommandArgument != null)
        {
            string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new string[] { "^" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            strCategory = commandArgs[0];
            strMonth = commandArgs[1];
            status = commandArgs[2];
            hdnBubbleId.Value = "rptTimeLine_btn" + strMonth + status;
            if (status == "B1")
            {
                status = "1";
            }
            else if (status == "B2")
            {
                status = "0";
            }
            else if (status == "B3")
            {
                status = "2";
            }
        }
        DataTable dtDistinctCategoryValues = new DataTable();
        Params = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Params["@status"] = Convert.ToInt32(status);
        Params["@monthShortName"] = strMonth;
        Params["@CategoryName"] = strCategory;
        Params["@idx_Client"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Client_id"]);
        string ProcName = "usp_getTaskDetailsByStatusCategoryAndMonth";
        dtGetTaskdetails = new BusinessLogicCore().ExecuteDataTable(ProcName, Params, connection);
        // to show the detailed view grid only bubble contain more than 1 task
        if (dtGetTaskdetails.Rows.Count > 1)
        {
            /*Commented on 03/15/2016*/
            DataView view = new DataView(dtGetTaskdetails);
            dtDistinctCategoryValues = view.ToTable(true, "CategoryName");
            RepeaterItem rptrow = ((sender as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button).NamingContainer as RepeaterItem);
            Repeater rptDetailsView = (Repeater)rptrow.FindControl("rptMarketingTimeLineDetiledView");
            rptDetailsView.DataSource = dtDistinctCategoryValues;
            rptDetailsView.DataBind();
            ImageButton imgPlus = (ImageButton)rptrow.FindControl("imgPlus");
            ImageButton imgMinus = (ImageButton)rptrow.FindControl("imgMinus");
            hdnDetailsView.Value = "bubble";
            hdnShowTaskDiv.Value = "0";
            hdnMonthName.Value = "";
            hdnIdx_task.Value = "";
            hdnlnkTaskId.Value = "";
            //   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ExpandBubbleGrid", "ExpandDiv('" + imgPlus.ClientID + "', '" + imgMinus.ClientID + "');", true);
        }
    }

    protected void rptMarketingTimeLineMonthDetiledView_ItemDataBound(object   sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            GridView gridView = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("GVMarketingTimeLineMonthlyDetiledView");
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                DataRowView dataRowView = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
                gridView.DataSource = GetPolicyDetailsByCategory(Convert.ToString(dataRowView["CategoryName"]));
                gridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Above give is my code behind code.

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnDecB1" runat="server" rel="popover" data- toggle="popover" OnCommand="BubbleButton_Command" OnClientClick="return false;" CommandName="Expand" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CategoryName")+"^Dec^B1"%>' Style="display: none;" onmouseover="dotBlink(this.id);" onmouseout="removedotBlink(this.id);" />
<div id="myPopover1" class="popover">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarketingTimeLineDetiledView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptMarketingTimeLineDetiledView_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="tblDetiledView">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="margin-bottom: 10px; background-color: white;">
                    <td style="text-align: left;" nowrap="true">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CategoryName") %>' CssClass="fontBold" Style="color: #23356E;"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GVMarketingTimeLineDetiledView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" Style="width: 100%;" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineDetailedGridHeaderStyle" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="idx_task" ToolTip="Select a row to edit task details.">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CDE5F5" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskName" HeaderText="Task Name" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineitem" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" ItemStyle-Width="12%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineHeader" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" ItemStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineitem" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientContacts" HeaderText="Client Contact" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineitem" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusName" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineHeader" ItemStyle-CssClass="MarketingTimeLineitem" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

And above one is aspx code
And my javascript code is

```
 $('[rel="popover"]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.popover({
        offset: 10,
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'right',
        html: true,
        content: $('#myPopover1').text(),
    });
    $('#mypopover').click(function () {
        $(".popover").popover('hide');
    });
});
```

When I click on the button the page is refreshed and if I give `OnClientClick="return false;"` it will on go to oncommand function. How can I get the details of repeater and grid view in popup?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Or you can place your Repeater inside UpdatePanel.